# Understanding the units of columns in MaFaulDa Dataset

Tags: motors, automotive-engineering, vibration

Recently I am learning about the MaFaulDa machine failure database. I am wondering about the unit of column zero (tachometer signal) measured by Monarch Instrument MT-190 (as announced by database publisher). How to convert that data to rpm?
Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: Please provide more info about the database and sensor.  There are several ways to use a tachometer- duration between ticks vs ticks per sec are essentially period vs frequency.

Comment: most of my knowledge and information about databases I get here:
[link](http://www02.smt.ufrj.br/~offshore/mfs/page_01.html). 
I have done the calculation according to the instructions below. I think it's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is TTL data, i.e. they are pulses of either 5V or 0V.
The figure shows the first 20,000 rows of column-1 from one of the CSV files in the database.

[image]

To find the rotational speed, you can measure the period, say $\tau$, between the rising edge of two adjacent pulses. Note that the sampling frequency is 50 kHz (you need that fact to determine your time-axis).

Assuming that there is only one pulse per revolution, you find the speed in revolutions per second by $f=1/\tau$, which is equal to the pulse frequency. Then, let $n_\text{rpm}$ denote the speed in RPM:
$$n_\text{rpm}=60f=\frac{60}{\tau}$$
For the case shown, $\tau \approx 0.07$ sec so
$$n_\text{rpm}=\frac{60}{0.07}\approx 857.1 \text{  rev/min}$$
Note the assumption that there is only one pulse per revolution !

Answer (score 0):

Thank Ronny Landsverk for helping!
I built a python code based on your instructions. It worked fine for my project.

```
def CaculateRPM(data_raw_speed):
    # Hiệu chỉnh lại đồ thị
    index_1_logic = np.where(data_raw_speed > 3)
    index_0_logic = np.where(data_raw_speed < 3)
    data_raw_speed[index_1_logic] = 5.0
    data_raw_speed[index_0_logic] = 0.0

    arrIndex = []
    rpmArr = np.zeros(data_raw_speed.shape[0])
    for i in range(data_raw_speed.shape[0]-1):
        if data_raw_speed[i+1] - data_raw_speed[i] == 5.0:
            arrIndex.append(i)
        else:
            continue

    for i in range(len(arrIndex) - 1):
        rpm = 3000000/(arrIndex[i+1] - arrIndex[i])
        rpmArr[arrIndex[i]:arrIndex[i+1]] = rpm

    rpmArr[0:arrIndex[0]] = rpmArr[arrIndex[1]+10]
    rpmArr[arrIndex[len(arrIndex)-1]:rpmArr.shape[0]] =  rpmArr[arrIndex[len(arrIndex)-1]-10]
    return pd.Series(rpmArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be an easier method for determining the speed of the machine (I found it with the help of Bing AI):

from scipy.signal import find_peaks

##### detect peaks

peaks, _ = find_peaks(sig, prominence=3) ##since we want to determine the intervals between any peaks >3

##### calculate interval between peaks

interval = (peaks[1] - peaks[0])*0.00002
speed = 50/interval

print(interval, speed)

where sig = signal.iloc[:,0] since the first column (zeroth column) is the speed sensor's voltage readings. I hope this helps, as I have a very difficult time to transfer learning a model from this signal to CWRU (with a speed of ~1750 CPM)